# Conditional statement does not work correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why I always have 'error' and none from 'if-else'?

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2015-01-01'

BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @ROZNICA AS INT;
    SET @ROZNICA = DATEDIFF(day, @Date, getdate());

    IF @ROZNICA = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Data podana w parametrze jest datą bieżącą.';
    END;
    ELSE IF @ROZNICA > 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Między datą obecną a datą ' + getdate() + ' jest ' + @ROZNICA + ' dni różnicy.';
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Data podana w parametrze jest większa od bieżacej.';
    END;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Error';
END CATCH;
```

I want something from the If Else statement to be displayed

Comment: If you intend to catch errors, how will you know what happened if all you do is print 'Error'? Learning to debug your own code is essential to writing code.

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
'Między datą obecną a datą ' + getdate() + ' jest ' + @ROZNICA + ' dni różnicy.';
```

with

```
PRINT concat('Między datą obecną a datą ', getdate(), ' jest ', @ROZNICA, ' dni różnicy.');
```

You get this because there is an error for casting datetime to varchar.
So your code will be

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2015-01-01'

BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @ROZNICA AS INT;
    SET @ROZNICA = DATEDIFF(day, @Date, getdate());
    IF @ROZNICA = 0
      BEGIN
        PRINT 'Data podana w parametrze jest datą bieżącą.';
      END --Remove ; from here
    ELSE IF @ROZNICA >0
      BEGIN
        PRINT concat('Między datą obecną a datą ', getdate(), ' jest ', @ROZNICA, ' dni różnicy.');
      END -- Remove ; from here
    ELSE
      BEGIN
        PRINT 'Data podana w parametrze jest większa od bieżacej.';
      END;
END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Error';
  END CATCH;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate a date or an integer with a varchar without conversion, so you need:

```
 PRINT 'Między datą obecną a datą ' + cast(getdate() as varchar(10)) + ' jest ' + cast( @ROZNICA  as varchar(5))+ ' dni różnicy.';
```